# Describe (briefly) the ring structure of the following rings and their characteristics: $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Describe (briefly) the ring structure of the following rings and their characteristics:

(a) $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(2)$.

**attemtp**: Let 2 be an ideal of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $(2) = 2[x]$ denote the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by 2. Then $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)[x]$.
and $(2)$ is a prime ideal , $(2)$ is a maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$. ANd $(2) $ is a PID since the coefficients lie in the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

characteristic of the ring is zero.

(b)  $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(x)$.

**attempt:** The ideal $(x)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ . And $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

characteristic is zero.

(c) $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(x^2)$.

**attempt:** Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, then  $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ is not a field. And   $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(x^2) $ = {$p(x) + (x^2) : p(x) \in \mathbb{Z[x]} $}.

$\mathbb{Z[x]}/(x^2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/x^2)[x]$.

characteristic is zero.

(d) $\mathbb{Z[x,y]}/(x^2, y^2, 2)$.

**attempt**: $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ is not a principal ideal domain.

Can someone please verify? I dont' reallyknow what are some things I could describe in general about the rings . And I am having trouble with part $d)$ , can someone please help? Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean when you say $(2)$ is a PID? It's an ideal, not an integral domain.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\# & \text{ring structure} & \text{characteristic}\\
\hline
\text{(a)} & \Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}_2[x] & \text{char }\Bbb{Z}_2[x]=2\\
\hline
\text{(b)} & \Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z} & \text{char }\Bbb{Z}=0\\
\hline
\text{(c)} & \Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2\rangle=\{a_0+a_1 x\mid a_0, a_1\in \Bbb{Z}\} & \text{char }\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2\rangle=0\\
\hline
\text{(d)} & \Bbb{Z}[x, y]/\langle x^2, y^2, 2\rangle=\{a x+bxy+cy+d\mid a, b, c, d\in \Bbb{Z}_2\} & \text{char }\Bbb{Z}[x, y]/\langle x^2, y^2, 2\rangle=2\\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2)$ is two, not zero.

For $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$, you say, "Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not a field". But $R[X]$ is not a field for any ring $R$, since $X$ has no inverse.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$ can be thought of as the linear polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: I was reading in my book if $p$ is a prime, the ring Z/2Z[x] obtained by reducing Z[x] modulo the prime ideal (p) is a principal ideal domain, since the coefficients lie in the field Z/pZ.  So that is where I got the information.

Comment: Do you think just mentioning the ring as the linear polynomials with integer coefficient is sufficient for describing the ring?

Comment: You are correct that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} [X]$ is a PID. But you said $(2)$ is a PID. You should also describe the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$ and those polynomials.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z[x]}/(x^2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/x^2)[x]$? I am assuming this from a general proposition.

Comment: I feel like you're misunderstanding some of the material in your book, and are trying to mimic earlier examples. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/(x^2)$ is meaningless; $(x^2)$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ (it's not even contained in it!) so you can't form this quotient.